# Spring JPA generic base repository

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot

This is probably similar to few other questions that were asked already but i could not find exact answer to the error i was getting. I am trying to build generic base class in Spring JPA

Base interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository <T, ID extends Serializable>
{
    public T handleCustom(String id);
}
```

Implementation class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
 implements GenericRepository<T, ID>
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    Class type;

    public T handleCustom(String id)
    {
        Annotation[] ann = type.getAnnotations();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Domain specific class:

```
public interface DomainRepository 
   extends JpaRepository<Domain, String>,
   GenericRepository<Domain, String>
{

}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Domain extends ParentEntity
{
    @Id
    private String domainId;
    private String domainName;

    public Domain()
    {

    }
    //setters getters
   .....
}
```

Config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.rabbitmq.jpa" )
public class JPAConfig
{
}
```

Following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'domainRepository': 
       Invocation of init method failed; 
       nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: 
    No property handleCustom found for type Domain!
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories

Answer (score 3):

I got this working with the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.rabbitmq.jpa",repositoryBaseClass = GenericRepositoryImpl.class )
public class JPAConfig
{
}
```

Base interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository <T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>
{
    public T handleCustom(String id);
}
```

Implementation class:

```
    @NoRepositoryBean
    public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements GenericRepository<T, ID>
    {
        protected final EntityManager entityManager;

        public GenericRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityInformation, entityManager);
            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        Class type;

        public T handleCustom(String id)
        {
            Annotation[] ann = type.getAnnotations();

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Domain Specific class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface DomainRepository extends GenericRepository <Domain, String>
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of your custom repository functionality must be the name of the Spring Data interface + "Impl" and not the name of ypur interface + "Impl".
Therefore in your case the implementation class must be DomainRepositoryImpl instead of GenericRepositoryImpl.

See the spring document for reference.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations